# Файлы MYD, MYI, frm залить в новую базу / MySQL

Tags: mysql

После того как сломал базу данных остались лишь файлы MYD, MYI, frm. Установил с чистого листа mysql - скопировал файлы MYD, MYI, frm в /var/lib/mysql. Думал, что поможет, но не тут то было. Я вижу только пустые базы без табличек. Как можно восстановить данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Были проблемы с правами... Решение: chmod 775 *